# INNER join two PySpark dataframe on the user defined functions [next Date]

Tags: python, pyspark, inner-join, apache-spark-sql

Here is my two PySpark Dataframe

```
a = sc.parallelize([['2017-05-14', 'foo' , 24 , 'abc'],
                    ['2017-05-16', 'user1', 26, 'mno'],  
                    ['2017-05-17', 'user2', 26, 'mno'],
                    ['2017-05-19', 'user2', 27, 'mno'], 
                    ['2017-05-19', 'user3', 28, 'mno']])
.toDF(['A_Date', 'user', 'id','info'])

b = sc.parallelize([['2017-05-15', 'foo', 24, 'def'],
                    ['2017-05-22', 'user2', 27, 'mno'], 
                    ['2017-05-20', 'user3', 28, 'mno']])
.toDF(['B_Date', 'user', 'id','info'])
```

[image]

and i want to join two dataframe  compairing some dataframe and date of dataframe in a joined data should be just less than dataframe b as shown below.

```
c = sc.parallelize([['2017-05-15', 'foo', 24, 'def', '2017-05-14'],
                    ['2017-05-22', 'user2', 27, 'mno', '2017-05-19'],
                    ['2017-05-20', 'user3', 28,'mno','2017-05-19']])
                    .toDF(['B_Date', 'user', 'id','info', 'A_Date'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach..

```
b.join(a,((a.A_Date<b.B_Date)  & (a.user == b.user)))\
.select(b.B_Date,b.user,b.id,b.info,a.A_Date)\
.groupby('B_Date','user','id','info')\
.agg(F.max("A_Date").alias("A_Date"))\
.sort('B_Date')\
.show()
```

This results in the required output:

```
+----------+-----+---+----+----------+
|    B_Date| user| id|info|    A_Date|
+----------+-----+---+----+----------+
|2017-05-15|  foo| 24| def|2017-05-14|
|2017-05-20|user3| 28| mno|2017-05-19|
|2017-05-22|user2| 27| mno|2017-05-19|
+----------+-----+---+----+----------+
```

This could be relatively slow because of the cross join.

Alternatively you can use a window function:

```
a_lagged = a.withColumn('prev_A_Date', F.lag(a['A_Date']).over(windowSpec))

b.join(a_lagged,((a_lagged.A_Date<b.B_Date) & ((a.A_Date>a_lagged.prev_A_Date) | a_lagged.prev_A_Date.isNull() )  & (a_lagged.user == b.user)))\
.select(b.B_Date,b.user,b.id,b.info,a_lagged.A_Date)\
.sort('B_Date')\
.show()
```

This also gives:

```
+----------+-----+---+----+----------+
|    B_Date| user| id|info|    A_Date|
+----------+-----+---+----+----------+
|2017-05-15|  foo| 24| def|2017-05-14|
|2017-05-20|user3| 28| mno|2017-05-19|
|2017-05-22|user2| 27| mno|2017-05-19|
+----------+-----+---+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of `join`

```
def join(self, other, on=None, how=None):
    """Joins with another :class:`DataFrame`, using the given join expression.

    :param other: Right side of the join
    :param on: a string for the join column name, a list of column names,
        a join expression (Column), or a list of Columns.
        If `on` is a string or a list of strings indicating the name of the join column(s),
        the column(s) must exist on both sides, and this performs an equi-join.
    :param how: str, default 'inner'.
        One of `inner`, `outer`, `left_outer`, `right_outer`, `leftsemi`.
```

Its clear the `on` parameter can be any condition. So you can do the following *for checking the dates while joining*.

```
b.join(a, [a.user == b.user, a.id == b.id, a.A_Date < b.B_Date]).select(b.B_Date, b.user, b.id, a.A_Date)
```

You should have your desired output `dataframe`

Comment: There are lots of data , which support the condition of user/id  and lots of data is [ a.A_Date < b.B_Date ] . The answer enlighten me to see the source of built-in functions. But it join with every greater data , but i need latest a.A_date to be smaller that b.B_Date

Comment: You need a filter to filter in the latest one then. :)